# Random quote generator - 3 arrays with one onClick

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My dear friends, how are you? 
I need a little help from you. Here's the thing: last night, I decided to create one of those random quote generators type sites.

Having in mind that I possess little code skills (I'm a designer), I Googled my way through some tutorials and BAM - it worked!

But now, I want to make it a little more interesting. What I want is to have the same onClick to randomize 3 different arrays and damn, not working. If I refresh the page, it works, but the button, nada.

I'm sure this is not a big deal, but I'm stuck. I was wondering if anyone of you is feeling like helping out?

```js
var nome = ["Nome1",
"Nome2",
"Nome3",
          ]

var meio = [
"meio1",
"meio2",
"meio3",
            ]

var sufixo = ["X1",
"X2",
"X3",
            ]

var randomNome = Math.floor(Math.random()*nome.length);
var randomMeio = Math.floor(Math.random()*meio.length);
var randomSufixo = Math.floor(Math.random()*sufixo.length);

function writeAnswer() {
document.write("<h2>Noquestão " + nome[randomNome] + " opovo " + meio[randomMeio] + " enomais, " + sufixo[randomSufixo] + ".</h2>");
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Random Gen</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>RandomGen</h1>
 <div id="writeAnswer"> 
 <!-- Quotes will display here -->
</div>
<button onclick="writeAnswer()">alright</button>
<input type="button" onclick="writeAnswer" />

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically had it:

You just need to make `writeAnswer()` a real function, put the random generation inside it (should be random each time, not just once), and then call that once on page load and each time button is pressed :)

See full demo below:

```js
var nome = ["Nome1", "Nome2", "Nome3"]

var meio = ["meio1", "meio2", "meio3"]

var sufixo = ["X1", "X2", "X3"]

//real function (not commented out)
function writeAnswer() {

  //random generation each function call:
  var randomNome = Math.floor(Math.random()*nome.length);
  var randomMeio = Math.floor(Math.random()*meio.length);
  var randomSufixo = Math.floor(Math.random()*sufixo.length);
  
  //put the random text in the p tag with id of 'target':
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = "<h2>Noquestão " + nome[randomNome] + " opovo " + meio[randomMeio] + " enomais, " + sufixo[randomSufixo] + ".</h2>";
  
}

//call it once on page load:
writeAnswer()
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random Gen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RandomGen</h1>
    <div id="writeAnswer">  
    <!-- Quotes will display here -->
</div>
<button onclick="writeAnswer()">alright</button>

<p id="target"></p>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it ;)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question please consider to mark as the accepted answer and up-vote it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow